# Difference between scipy.stats.norm.pdf and plotting gaussian manually

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gaussian

I'm plotting a simple normal distribution using scipy.stats, but for some reason when I try to compare it to the regular gaussian formula the plot looks very different:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

x = np.linspace(-50,175,10000)
sig1, mu1  = 10.0, 30.0

y1 = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu1, sig1)
y11 = np.exp(-(x-mu1)**2/2*sig1)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sig1))

plt.plot(x,y11)
plt.plot(x,y1)
```

The result is:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why they are not the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stats.norm.pdf` requires sigma, but in your calculation you are using it as variance. Also there are two brackets missing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

x = np.linspace(-50, 175, 10000)
sig1, mu1 = 10.0, 30.0
var1 = sig1 ** 2

y1 = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu1, sig1)
y11 = np.exp(-((x - mu1) ** 2) / (2 * var1)) / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var1))

plt.plot(x, y11)
plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.show()
```

Which produces the same plot.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have a mistake. Parentheses are missing for the denominator in the exponential of the manual gaussian.

Furthermore, the third argument of `scipy.norm.pdf` is the standard deviation (sigma), but that appears in the gaussian PDF squared (sigma^2).

The corrected code would be

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

x = np.linspace(-50,175,10000)
sig1, mu1  = 10.0, 30.0

y1 = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu1, sig1)
y11 = np.exp(-(x-mu1)**2/(2*sig1**2))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sig1**2))


plt.plot(x,y1,label="scipy",alpha=0.85)
plt.plot(x,y11,ls="--",label="custom")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

Which outputs:

[image]